# Why doesn't the compiler let me use a variable in a switch case?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a program that outputs the most used character in a file.

Why does the compiler give me an error when I try this:

```
    for (char i = 97 ; i <=122 ; i ++) {
        switch (x) {

                case i :  
                break;
        }
    }
```

This code uses a switch to get the most used characters. The error is :

```
'i' cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

Comment: Because it's against the spec.

Comment: @xaxxon Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the loop, `case` "parameters" are required to be constant, and `i` is not.

Comment: @xaxxon OK, but why did the language creators decide to prohibit such use?

Comment: if you use case:i and want to do anything with the variable i, you definitely use a function to do that, then you don't need switch at all

Comment: @gaazkam that's not an appropriate question for stack overflow.

Comment: I'm trying to make a program that outputs the most used character in a file

Comment: @MarinMaksutaj make a 256 element int array, set it to 0.   then say array[my_char]++.  Then, when you're done, iterate over the array and figure out which one has the highest count.

Comment: @xaxxon Thanks for the help.

Comment: @gaazkam, `case` operators are usually optimized, e.g. transformed into binary tree searches, to speedup the match. Dynamic cases would not make sense this way because then you needed to build the tree first and you'd rather go with linear matching. To not complicate matters they are left as is. You can define your own `case`-like primitives, either in form of preprocessor macros or as functions, to accept variable alternatives. Care about the evaluation order though: in function call, all the actual arguments are evaluated BEFORE the function invoked, which is not the case with chained `if`s.

Comment: @xaxxon:  Better to use `std::array` or `std::[unordered_]map` than a raw C-style array.

Comment: @MartinBonner maybe?  not really.   maps are overkill and have an awful API.  std:;array.. whatever.

Comment: @bipll Why don't you convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: Strictly speaking, that would be an answer to the follow-up question which you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case` labels need to be compile time constants, and you are trying to use variable `i`, so you get the rather descriptive error message.

If you need to test against variables, the direct replacement is if-else if-...-else ladder. Though your simple case has no "else" part, Additionally, `break` breaks out of the `switch`, so you can't use it to break out of a loop then (direct replacement would be to use `goto` but it's *far* better to rethink your logic in almost all cases).

So write your code like this:

```
for (char i = 97 ; i <=122 ; i ++) {
    if (x == i) {
       break; // did you mean to break the loop?

    }
}
```

Comment: Also worth commenting that the OP probably thinks he is iterating 'a' to 'z' - but the C++ standard doesn't guarantee that, and in fact there are machines where that is not true.

Comment: @hyde Thanks, I  understand it now. (I'm a beginner)

Comment: @MartinBonner I'm mostly of the opinion, that pointing that out is just useless information overload for someone just learning C++... But a matter of pedagogic opinion, that.